# QGIS Rule-based rendering in 2.14

Tags: qgis, symbology, open-source-gis, sqlite

I'm going through the [QGIS Map Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0989421759) book and have run up against a wall in adding cascading rules.  I'm working with QGIS LTR 2.14.  The authors recommend this version.

My vector data is in a SQLite db.  I used ogr2ogr to convert it from the planet .pbf file.

I've created an extended subcategory rule from "motorway" called "motorway bridge" and used the following SQL to do so:

`"other_tags" LIKE '%"bridge"=>"yes"%' OR "other_tags" LIKE '%"bridge"=>"viaduct"%'`

This SQL yields a total of 6273 results.  So far so good!

Now, I go ahead and right-click on that rule and select "Refine current rule" --> "Add categories to rule."

To create my level 1 bridge style, I use the following SQL, which should only run on the results in the parent filter; namely, only bridges.

`"other_tags" NOT LIKE '%"layer"=>"2"%'`

However, when I test this, it yields *118145* features, which means that it's  clearly ignoring the parent query.

This may be a bug in 2.14; I'm inclined to say it is, otherwise, what is the point of using the "Refine current rule" function?  Has anyone else run into this?  I can write a whole bunch of explicit SQL to get around it, but wanted to make sure I'm not doing this wrong.

Comment: I think it's just the count test that's wrong - does it render correctly?

Answer (score 2):

So this has been open for a few days and I thought I'd answer my own question.  @ndawson got it right in the comments: the features render correctly, it's just the count test that is wrong.

So, for what it's worth, if you're working with 2.14 and doing rule-based symbology, don't get too hung up on the count test!